# Drupal: Any way to detect if a view's path is changed?

Tags: drupal, view

A long shot..I know.

Is it possible to detect if a view's page display path is changed via views UI? Is there some kind of hook that I could use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the Views UI is implemented, but one idea is to implement `hook_form_alter()` on the view editing form and detect any changes to the values with a custom submit function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make the short story long.

You can't to the best of my knowledge hook into changes in a view when they are made.

You can however create the view as a feature and detect any changes made that way by storing the view as code.